# Arabic digit to English digit android

Tags: android

I am using this code for translate English digit into Arabic. But now i am trying to change Arabic digits into English digit.

```
private void decimalToArabic() {
    String str = showOutputEdit.getText().toString();
    char[] arabicChars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
    //  char[] arabicChars = {'٩','٨','٧','٦','٥','٤','٣','٢','١','٠'};
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
        { 
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                builder.append(arabicChars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);
            }
            else
            {
                builder.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number in English : "+str);
        System.out.println("Number In Arabic : "+builder.toString() );
        showOutputEdit.setText(builder.reverse().toString());
}
```

what should i need to change?

Answer (score 4):

i think you can use something like this.(Here i convert integer to arabic)

```
 public String convertToArabic(int value)
{
    String newValue =   (((((((((((value+"").replaceAll("1", "١")).replaceAll("2", "٢")).replaceAll("3", "٣")).replaceAll("4", "٤")).replaceAll("5", "٥")).replaceAll("6", "٦")).replaceAll("7", "٧")).replaceAll("8", "٨")).replaceAll("9", "٩")).replaceAll("0", "٠"));       
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: it works for single digit. but i have a set of digits in string.

Comment: one example please ??

Comment: it can be use for any digit. for example convertToArabic(4567) gives string value of arabic of 4567

Answer (score 3):

```
private static String arabicToenglish(String number) 
{
  char[] chars = new char[number.length()];
  for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++) {
    char ch = number.charAt(i);
    if (ch >= 0x0660 && ch <= 0x0669)
      ch -= 0x0660 - '0';
    else if (ch >= 0x06f0 && ch <= 0x06F9)
      ch -= 0x06f0 - '0';
    chars[i] = ch;
  }
  return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

arabic chars array must be reversed

**WRONG**

```
char[] chars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
```

**RIGHT**

```
char[] chars = {'٩','٨','٧','٦','٥','٤','٣','٢','١','٠'};
```

It is just because of stackoverflow editor, but if you will copy text and paste (`CTRL + C` `CTRL + V`) it will work just fine.

so function will look like this

```
private static String toArabicDigits(String eng) {

    char[] chars = {'٩','٨','٧','٦','٥','٤','٣','٢','١','٠'};
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < eng.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isDigit(eng.charAt(i))) {
            builder.append(chars[(int)(eng.charAt(i))-48]);
            System.out.println("char - " + eng.charAt(i) + " " + (int)(eng.charAt(i)-48) + " - " + chars[(int)(eng.charAt(i))-48]);
        } else {
            builder.append(eng.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String convertArabic(String arabicStr) {
  char[] chArr = arabicStr.toCharArray();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (char ch : chArr) {
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
      sb.append(Character.getNumericValue(ch));
    } else {
      sb.append(ch);
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```