# NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "٢"

Tags: java, android, double

After a simple division, I try to round the result to 2 decimal places. Everything works fine, but on some devices, I am getting this symbol "٢" as the result of the division. This symbol then causes a number format exception when I try to round it to 2 decimal places. 
Can someone explain to me why this is happening, and how I can resolve it

my code:

```
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for (HashMap.Entry<String, Double> entry : ratings.entrySet()) {
        String person = entry.getKey();
        Double rating = entry.getValue();
        total += rating;
    }
    average = total / ratings.size();

    ratingsDisplay.setTitleText(roundTo2Decimals(average) + "");

public double roundTo2Decimals(double val) {
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    return Double.valueOf(df2.format(val)); <== this is where the crash happens
}
```

Error log:

```
0java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "٢"
1at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
2at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
3at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
4at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
5at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
6at com.ducky.flipplanet.ToonViewer.roundTo2Decimals(ToonViewer.java:2750)
7at com.ducky.flipplanet.ToonViewer.calculateAndShowRatings(ToonViewer.java:2919)
8at com.ducky.flipplanet.ToonViewer.loadFromDocId(ToonViewer.java:2850)
9at com.ducky.flipplanet.ToonViewer$79.onDataChange(ToonViewer.java:4816)
10at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:53)
11at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
12at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
13at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
14at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
15at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
16at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
17at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
18at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
19at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
20at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: The “٢” symbol is arabic number. i.e equal to 2 so before doing any operation convert then into normal state

Comment: @shahid17june Thankyou for the pointer; but how do i know they are in the wrong state and how do I convert it to the right state.

Comment: it would be helpful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778734/arabic-digit-to-english-digit-android
and just do google there are lots of questions are already exists like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("####.00").format(d).replace("٠", "0")
                    .replace("١", "1").replace("٢", "2").replace("٣", "3")
                    .replace("٤", "4").replace("٥", "5").replace("٦", "6")
                    .replace("٧", "7").replace("٨", "8").replace("٩", "9")
                    .replace("٫", "."));
```

// based on Sweeper answer :)

Answer (score 7):

The character that you are getting is called a `ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO` in Unicode.

Here are the other digits:

```
٠ 0
١ 1
٢ 2
٣ 3
٤ 4
٥ 5
٦ 6
٧ 7
٨ 8
٩ 9
```

One way to fix this is replacing the digits to turn them into English by `replace`. However, this might not work for some cases. Also, you should be aware that there are other number systems in the world.

Therefore, you should set the locale of the decimal format to `en_US` instead. This way, no weird characters will come out.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.applyPattern("###.##");
String fString = formatter.format(100);
System.out.println(fString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String result = String.format(Locale.US,"%.2f", INT_VALUE);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)